# Is it practical to cache multiple instances of variable API data (updates hourly for each instance) for N users?

Tags: python, optimization, caching, flask

I'm using flask with SQLAlchemy on a postgresql database for a mobile app I'm building. My application allows a single user to save lets say up to 5 different locations which are saved in the database.

For each of these locations, I'm serving data from a different API and each of these API calls depend on the specific location and the data itself updates hourly.

A simple PUT operation that gets all N locations for a given user, makes N calls to the API with each location, and updates the database, is quite time consuming. (roughly 3.5 seconds for only 3-4 locations)

I was trying to implement some caching, but since the caching will be done for each location every hour, I'm wondering if that's efficient or practical to do on the server side. My argument is say you have 50 users, each with 5 locations, that means every hour, the application will try to do 250 API calls all on the server side and store all that cache in one place and this will grow really quickly becoming really time consuming.

Basically, this is storing weather data for each location a user wants to monitor. But that weather data would update every hour on the API so I need a way to refresh that data (get new data from API based on latitude and longitude) and update the weather data for that location(and user) in the database.

Is there a simpler way to optimize this on the server side or should this caching be done locally on the mobile app side in the background somehow?

Comment: I don't see where the exponential growth is coming from - based on your description, the number of calls will be linear with the number of users. Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: Ignoring the fact you may have to recheck what [exponential growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth) means, I think your question is unclear. What kind of data are your users saving per location? Is the data individually separated per user, with no external influence? Is it shared somehow? What's the size of the data chunks (per user/location)? Would data in a local cache on the mobile client become invalid over time? Please clarify.

Comment: another comment requesting clarification: _"the caching will be done for each location every hour...every hour, the application will try to do 250 API calls all on the server"_. This seems to imply that you'd be proactively caching data you anticipate the client requesting in the future. Just to be clear, "caching" (usually) means that an initial client request is stored (cached) so that subsequent requests serve the same value without making another backend API call. (If that's what you meant, ignore this comment.) Cache would of course have to be invalidated (or expire) when out of date.

Comment: That's right, this wont actually be exponential growth, but linear. Still though, it becomes extremely time and memory consuming to run up to 5 API calls on the server for every user in the database at every hour. 

@michael, So the cache would be replaced by new data from the API and when the user opens the app, it would refresh the data, but from the cache instead of making new API calls. I updated the post to clarify what the use case is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is stored on a server, you should look at sending push notifications instead of polling. Push notifications run at or below the telephony level, basically no cost, no need for the device to be awake, so no cost in battery life either. At the server level, for example on an iPhone you would send ONE message to Apple which can handle it better than you can.

So on the device you can store the data and whether it is still valid. And then you can decide when to download a newer version of the data.